# Block pip inside Docker - Windows Server

Tags: python, windows, docker, pip, firewall

I'm building a Docker container that have python and import some packages using 'pip install'.

I want to allow 'pip' to communicate only with pypi.org, and block it from communicating with any other channel, including the host that runs the docker container (in which we run the pip).

I tried to create some custom outbound rules in firewall (including blocking the container's IP address, the container's gateway IP address, and the entire 'nat' docker subnet), but somehow it keeps going around the firewall and having access to wherever it wants (and imports any package it tries).

*To clarify, I'm first trying to block 'pip' entirely, even for pypi.org*

Is it possible to achieve this blocking behavior? What rules should I set in Firewall (or directly in the docker network)?

*I'm running on Windows desktop with Docker desktop, and the container is running with the following image - mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1809.

Comment: Sounds like an [x y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the problem you trying to solve with this?